# How are methods accessed for c# properties? (Specifically if the property is a collection and using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface)

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say we have SomeProperty of type List that we have get and set methods for

```
public List<SomeClass> SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        //return something
    }
    set
    {
        //set something
    }
}
```

I was wondering whether the get or set methods are called when a method of SomeProperty (i.e. `SomeProperty.Add(someObject);`) is called.

I'm wondering because I have a wpf window that has a List as a Property, (let's call it `ListProperty`), that needs to update another property for display (let's call it `DisplayProperty`) using the implemented methods of INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm wondering if I should put the `OnPropertyChanged` event in get or set

ie:

```
public List<SomeClass> ListProperty
{
    get
    {
        //return something
    }
    set
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayProperty");
    }
}
```

or is there a better solution to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the setter will not be called by anything modifying the collection. The `ObservableCollection` class exists for this particular purpose - you can use it in the place of your list. You should still use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have it as a property with change notification, so that if the entire collection is replaced, the event for that will fire.

**Edit, Sample:**

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _someProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_someProperty == value) return;
        _someProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `SomeProperty.Add(someObject);` you're calling the getter, and not the setter.  You're then mutating the propery that is returned by the getter.

Notifying of the property change in the getter would be wrong on multiple levels.  First, on a practical level, you're mutating the value returned by the property *after* the value is returned, so the property changed event would fire before the change is even made.  Second, it's very confusing to consumers of your code to expect a property change event to fire just because you're getting the value of a property.

If you want to know if the value of this collection is mutated, rather than just knowing if the collection that the property references is changed, you should use a specific collection type that allows you to observe when it is changed, such as `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

As all of the other answers mentioned, I switched the List over to an ObservableCollection but also encapsulated the Add method (`ListProperty.Add(someObject)`) into another method and called `OnPropertyChanged('DisplayProperty')` from that method

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ListProperty
{
    get
    {
        //return something
    }
    set
    {
        //set something
        OnPropertyChanged('ListProperty')
    }
}
public SomeClass DisplayProperty
{
    get
    {
        //returns something involving ListProperty
    }
    set
    {
        //set something
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayProperty");
    }
}
private void AddSomeItem(SomeClass item)
{
    //any extra code
    ListProperty.Add(item);
    OnPropertyChanged("DisplayProperty");
}
```

Comment: I would only fire the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event if the addition of an item changes what they would get from `DisplayProperty`, but, aside from that, looks right. You still want to invoke `OnPropertyChanged("ListProperty")` in the setter for `ListProperty`

Comment: Edited to match your suggestion